# HTTP response reason phrase always OK after ugrade to IIS 10

Tags: php, iis, header

My local dev environment is IIS 10 (came with Windows 10 upgrade), using PHP FastCGI. I'm working on some API endpoints and all PHP header responses, like `header(HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request);` and `header('HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed');` include the reason-phrase "OK". 200 OK, 400 OK, 403 OK, 404 OK.

This works fine using the same code base on pre-IIS 10 machines. Any ideas on what to look for in IIS config, FastCGI Settings, etc.. to troubleshoot this?